# nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to retrieve value from an entity which I am using and then display the total to the user. The method i am using works perfectly in a masterviewcontroler class i have but i have added this method to a another view controller class but i receive the error:

`'+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Incoming''`

homeviewcontroller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,ExpenseDataDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic) float outgoingTotal;
@property (nonatomic) float incomingTotal;
@end
```

homeviewcontroller.m:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "OutgoingHolder.h"
#import "Outgoing.h"
#import "IncomingHolder.h"
#import "Incoming.h"
@interface HomeViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblIncoming;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblOutgoing;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTotal;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self getIncomingTotal];
    _lblIncoming.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", self.incomingTotal];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)getIncomingTotal{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Incoming"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Incoming" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"incamount"]];
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;


    NSArray *dictionaries = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    NSLog (@"amount: %@",dictionaries);

    NSManagedObject *Object;


    for (int x =  0; x<[dictionaries count]; x++) {

        Object = [dictionaries objectAtIndex:x];
        self.incomingTotal = self.incomingTotal + [[Object valueForKey:@"incamount"]floatValue];

    }


    NSLog(@"%@",[@"Total INc: " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", self.incomingTotal]]);

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the managedObjectContext?

Comment: The error is telling you that `self.managedObjectContext` is nil - which is pretty obvious since you did not include any code that assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your root view controller, you can assign your managedObjectContext in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    MasterViewControler * masterViewControler = (MasterViewControler *)self.window.rootViewController;
    masterViewControler.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

For other view controllers add this

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context; //= nil; //explicit assignment to nil is unnecessary under ARC
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

And assign your managedObjectContext

```
self.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
```

Or you can pass managedObjectContext using `prepareForSegue`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"homeVCSegue"]) {
    HomeViewController *homeViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    homeViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Basically you want to keep passing the managedObjectContext from the AppDelegate.

Hope this will help!

Comment: One quick question. The values on this page are displayed according to what is entered in a tableview controller. How would I update this homepage as soon as someone does enter a number in the other view controller? Would i reload this view controller somehow?

Comment: Try calling `[self.tableView reloadData];`. Either in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. In long term you might want to populate your tableView with `NSFetchedResultsController` which updates the tableView as soon as the user edits data.

Comment: The tableView is being populated from NSFetchedResultsController, The homepage itself does not refresh unless I run the application again. I want the homepage to update everytime something is added in my tableView

Comment: @SFF I believe you mean `respondsToSelector:` rather than `performSelector:` in your second bit of sample code. Also, explicit assignment to nil is unnecessary under ARC.

Comment: @John Your homepage has `NSFetchedResultsController` property but I don't see any `UITableView` property. If you just need to update the view just call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: @SFF I tried calling this in the view did load but the view is still not updating

Comment: @John You may need to post a `NSNotification` to update the data of your view controller. Or use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).